# display property not working in media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

i have create a side bar button using html i want to display it in mobile screen so i am trying to showing it in mobile size i used display none for desktop size page now changing display type in media query doesn't working...

html code

```
 <div class="side_bar">
            
          <div class="web-menu" onClick="change()">
            <div class="line line-1"></div>
            <div class="line line-2"></div>
            <div class="line line-3"></div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

css code:

```
.web-menu{
  /* position: fixed; */
    display: none;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    right: 5rem;
    z-index: 200;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    cursor: pointer; 

}
.line{
    width: 80%;
    height: 0.25rem;
    background-color:black;
   
     
}  @media  screen and (max-width:900px){
.side_bar{
  display: flex;
  
}
 }
```

Comment: You are using `display: none` on the `.web-menu` but using the media query for `.side-bar`.

Answer (score 0):

With media query you should add displaying to `.web-menu` not to `.side_bar`

Comment: after removing side_bar div still not changing display in media query